# Show only one view in full screen in landscape mode when screen rotates

Tags: android, orientation, android-view, mpandroidchart

Integrated MPAndroid Line charts, when screen rotates to landscape I want to only graph view to be shown in full screen and all other things should be hidden. I have restricted orientation to "Portrait", how can I trigger when screen rotates to landscape even though it is restricted.

Comment: You can't, You have to remove that constraint. After removing it you can detect with the orientation of Activity whether it's portrait or landscape.

Answer (score 0):

you can duplicate the XML layout file of your activity, and put it inside folder /res/layout-land if you don't have it create it. Then you can change the visibility to "gone" at the views you don't want to show in landscape mode.
Also don't restrict the orientation to portrait for this activity